# Pass Database Name as a parameter to an Inline Function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, inline

I am trying to make an inline function that can be used in a few dozen stored procedures rather than placing the code in every single one. The function can be called by various databases so I need to be able to pass the database name as a parameter. In this case, the parameter is @dbname. Here is my code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_units]
     (
      @inReportControlId int,
      @dbname varchar(30)
     )

RETURNS table
AS

RETURN 

(      

WITH prep AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM
  (
  SELECT RTRIM(cp.Label) + 'ReportUnit' TYPE, RTRIM(cu.Label) value, rc.ReportControlId, curr.Symbol, curp.Prefix, curp.Factor
  FROM   @dbname.CorpConventionUnit AS ccu INNER JOIN
                         @dbname.CorpUnit AS cu ON ccu.NUnitId = cu.CorpUnitId INNER JOIN
                         @dbname.CorpProduct AS cp ON ccu.CorpProductId = cp.CorpProductId INNER JOIN
                         PhdReports.PhdRpt.ReportControl AS rc ON ccu.CorpConventionId = rc.ConventionId INNER JOIN
                         @dbname.CorpUnit AS cu2 ON cu2.CorpUnitId = cu.CorpBaseUnitId INNER JOIN
                         @dbname.CorpCurrency AS curr ON rc.CurrencyId = curr.CorpCurrencyId INNER JOIN
                         @dbname.CorpCurrencyPrefix AS curp ON rc.CurrencyPrefix = curp.Prefix  

  UNION ALL
  SELECT RTRIM(cp.Label) + 'BaseUnit' TYPE, RTRIM(cu2.Label) value, rc.ReportControlId, curr.Symbol, curp.Prefix, curp.Factor
  FROM   @dbname.CorpConventionUnit AS ccu INNER JOIN
                         @dbname.CorpUnit AS cu ON  ccu.NUnitId = cu.CorpUnitId INNER JOIN
                         @dbname.CorpProduct AS cp ON ccu.CorpProductId = cp.CorpProductId INNER JOIN
                         PhdReports.PhdRpt.ReportControl AS rc ON ccu.CorpConventionId = rc.ConventionId INNER JOIN
                        @dbname.CorpUnit AS cu2 ON cu2.CorpUnitId = cu.CorpBaseUnitId INNER JOIN
                         @dbname.CorpCurrency AS curr ON rc.CurrencyId = curr.CorpCurrencyId INNER JOIN
                         @dbname.CorpCurrencyPrefix AS curp ON rc.CurrencyPrefix = curp.Prefix

  UNION ALL 
  SELECT RTRIM(cp.Label) + 'ReportUnitDenom' TYPE, RTRIM(cu.Label) value, rc.ReportControlId, curr.Symbol, curp.Prefix, curp.Factor
  FROM   @dbname.CorpConventionUnit AS ccu INNER JOIN
                         @dbname.CorpUnit AS cu ON ccu.DUnitId = cu.CorpUnitId INNER JOIN
                         @dbname.CorpProduct AS cp ON ccu.CorpProductId = cp.CorpProductId INNER JOIN
                         PhdReports.PhdRpt.ReportControl AS rc ON ccu.CorpConventionId = rc.ConventionId INNER JOIN
                         @dbname.CorpUnit AS cu2 ON cu2.CorpUnitId = cu.CorpBaseUnitId INNER JOIN
                         @dbname.CorpCurrency AS curr ON rc.CurrencyId = curr.CorpCurrencyId INNER JOIN
                         @dbname.CorpCurrencyPrefix AS curp ON rc.CurrencyPrefix = curp.Prefix 
  )AS hi
  GROUP BY  hi.ReportControlId ,value, TYPE, hi.Symbol, hi.Prefix, hi.Factor

)



  Select ReportControlID,Symbol,Prefix, Factor,
     Min(Case TYPE When 'OilBaseUnit' Then value End) OilBaseUnit,
     Min(Case TYPE When 'NGLBaseUnit' Then value End) NGLBaseUnit,
     Min(Case TYPE When 'GasBaseUnit' Then value End) GasBaseUnit,
     Min(Case TYPE When 'OilReportUnit' Then value End) OilReportUnit,
     Min(Case TYPE When 'NGLReportUnit' Then value End) NGLReportUnit,
     Min(Case TYPE When 'GasReportUnit' Then value End) GasReportUnit,
     Min(Case TYPE When 'GORReportUnit' Then value End) GORReportUnit,
     Min(Case TYPE When 'GORReportUnitDenom' Then value End) GORReportUnitDenom,
     Min(Case TYPE When 'YieldReportUnit' Then value End) YieldReportUnit,
     Min(Case TYPE When 'YieldReportUnitDenom' Then value End) YieldReportUnitDenom,
     Min(Case TYPE When 'CondensateBaseUnit' Then value End) CondensateBaseUnit,
     Min(Case TYPE When 'CondensateReportUnit' Then value End) CondensateReportUnit
   From prep
   where ReportControlId = @inReportControlId
   Group By ReportControlId, Symbol,Prefix, Factor
```

Normally if this was just in a stored procedure, I would store the query in a varchar and use the replace command to replace @dbname with the database being used at the time. This doesn't seem to work in the inline function. So I figured I could pass in the dbname as a parameter to the function, however it will not let me save the function because it doesn't recognize "@dbname" as a valid database.

How can I replace the variable with the parameter passed in?

Comment: Sorry but not possible that I have ever run across.  Dynamic SQL is not allowed in User Defined Functions at all.  And as you have run across if you are defining a database name in the table selection it has to exist, in other words not a variable.

Comment: What I ended up doing is storing this as a varbinary in a table (so I could reuse it in multiple queries) and then converting it to a varchar and replacing @dbName with the name of the database currently connected to.